# CS1525: Invalid expression term ':' Error in MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

```
<%: ViewData["AllState"].ToString()%>
```

Error Find on this statement....
i am using the MVC2 Pattern.the Viewdata Return the List Type Value using the MVC Controller

**UPDATE**

```
public ActionResult About()
{ 
  Gramin_Live_18032015Entities objdatabase = new Gramin_Live_18032015Entities(); 
  var Datatable = (from Tbl_StateMaster in objdatabase.Tbl_StateMaster select Tbl_StateMaster).ToList();     
  ViewData["AllState"] = Datatable; 
  return View(); 
}
```

Comment: Just use `@` delimeter before `ViewData`.

Comment: public ActionResult About()
        {
            Gramin_Live_18032015Entities objdatabase = new Gramin_Live_18032015Entities();
            var Datatable = (from Tbl_StateMaster in objdatabase.Tbl_StateMaster select Tbl_StateMaster).ToList();
            ViewData["AllState"] = Datatable;
            return View();
        }

Comment: on view  <p>
        Put content here.
    </p>
     <%: ViewData["AllState"].ToString()%>

Comment: after using the delimeter <%@: ViewData["AllState"].ToString()%>

Comment: You need to edit your question (and use code formatting) when providing code rather than posting it in the comments. Please also read [Ask].

Comment: i will try for good question asps.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<%= ViewData["AllState"].ToString()%>
```

I think you are passing a list to viewdata and trying to use as a string. Try using foreach and try. please check the link

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views

Comment: after use that have a problem   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FirstApplication.Tbl_StateMaster]